# How to prevent rule `@angular-eslint/template/i18n` from linting `mat-icon` elements

Tags: angular, angular-material, eslint, angular-i18n

I use the rule `@angular-eslint/template/i18n` to lint elements in template that contains text node and doesn't have an `i18n` attribute.

The Angular Material `mat-icon` elements use inner text to identify the icon key like this :

```
<mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
```

As it contains text, it is being linted by eslint as well. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way add exceptions to this rule to exclude some element tags like `mat-icon`

Here is the eslint config I am using :

```
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/i18n": [
          "warn",
          {
            "checkId": false,
            "checkText": true,
            "checkAttributes": false
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Angular 14.1 and the support of the [SEO friendly ligature icons](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/24578), you should change your mat-icon usage like so:

```diff
- <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
+ <mat-icon fontIcon="home"></mat-icon>
```

This has the advantage of avoiding your i18n issue while also preventing your icon name to appear in Google search result page.